# Typescript - Anyway to achieve the following idea: typeof T[keyof T]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have been searching all over but can't seem to find an answer or i might be searching for the wrong elements.

But just as i'm able to express a union type of accessors using keyof T where T is a generic type , is there anyway to get the accompanying types of those respective keys?

To provide an example lets say we have the following object:

```
interface Data {
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

And a generic method:

```
const genericMethod = <T>(key: keyof T) => {
  console.log(key) // --> "name", "age"

  // Pseudo code idea, the idea is to get the appropriate type that correspond to our keyof
  console.log(typeof T[key]) // --> "string", "number"
}
```

Calling this method using the Data type as our generic will yield as expected a union type key holding all the properties of our Data interface, but i also want to be able to infer their respective types.

```
genericMethod<Data>(keyof Data);
```

Comment: Infer? What for? Your pseudo code shows something inherently impossible, as types (and in fact Interfaces) don't exist at runtime, so you cannot log them.

Comment: @IngoBürk thanks for the quick answer, i seems as if i have been looking at this the wrong way around as i also described in my answer to choz below. I wanted to log them as you guys correctly pointed out but i think i will have to find another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to log interfaces, they refer to nothing more a type but you're trying to log it as a value.

> How to achieve `typeof T[keyof T]`

Perhaps this is what you're looking for;

```
interface Data {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const genericMethod = <T>(TObject: T, key: keyof T) => {
  console.log(TObject) // --> "name", "age"

  // Pseudo code idea, the idea is to get the appropriate type that correspond to our keyof
  console.log(typeof TObject[key]) // --> typeof T[keyof T]?
}

const obj: Data = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 15
}

genericMethod<typeof obj>(obj, 'age');
```

Comment: Thanks! New to typescript and the whole not at runtime nature. It is exactly correct i wanted to log the interface. But anyway seeing as that is not possible i got a sanity check and it wasn't just because i couldn't see the forest from trees.

Comment: Kotlin has `reified types` that allow to access type information of generics in runtime. Maybe some day TS will offer such stuff too :) https://blog.mindorks.com/what-are-reified-types-in-kotlin